# Render JavaScript blocks with Yeoman?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

What would be the steps (pseudo code) to create a JavaScript repository class (or similar) using Yeoman?  Templates seem to be geared towards entire files, which would not work since methods would change.  And, I've found almost no generators that construct output using loops.

[This tutorial (link)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-yeoman-generator--cms-20040) goes into great depth but mentions nothing about either.

My goal would be to render a class file that would feed from an existing database and create one file per document or table.  Each class file would contain roughly:

```
vars for all sibling models
vars for all required utilities

1 x create function
    - input parameters (N x params ... based on table fields)
    - validation of parameters (N x statements ... based on table fields)
    - construction of query (based entirely on table fields)
    - execution

N x get function (N x methods ... based on indicies on table)
    - input parameters (N x params ... based on table fields)
    - validation of parameters (N x statements ... based on table fields)
    - construction of query (based entirely on table fields)
    - execution

... etc., etc., etc.
```

Am I correct in assuming that every parameter signature... every validation statement... every query... would have to be constructed with strings on the fly?  And, that there is no sub-template or looping logic built into Yeoman?  This isn't a big deal.  I'm just surprised a generation utility with such popularity would require so much manual hacking.

Edit...
[Here's another tutorial (link).](http://stephenplusplus.github.io/yeoman.io/generators.html)  The author is manually building HTML by concatenating strings.  Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Yeoman provides [Lodash templates](https://lodash.com/docs#template) support when you call `this.fs.copyTpl()` (or the legacy `this.template()`).

Lodash supports loops and multiple kind of operations in a template. An option is to use them.

Otherwise, you can build/edit a file using the JavaScript AST (abstract syntax tree). There's multiple node modules able to do so, you just need to pick one. As this is not a problem space specific to Yeoman, it make sense for us to let generator authors choose the tool they prefer.

For what it's worth, [AST Query](https://github.com/SBoudrias/AST-query) is an option to easily modify an AST. AST Query is the tool we use in core for the Gruntfile API in Yeoman.